# Angular2 setting a user asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular, angular-fullstack

I am trying to pull a user's information and set it to my user variable as follows. I am using the angular-fullstack boilerplate.

```
this.getCurrentUser = this.Auth.getCurrentUser;
this.getCurrentUser(function(data){
    console.log('data: ', data); 
    this.username = data.name;
});
```

But when doing so, I get an error that `this.username` is not defined. Thus, my question is how can I put the relevant information into my variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for the callback since

> Arrow functions capture the `this` value of the enclosing context

```
this.getCurrentUser = this.Auth.getCurrentUser;
this.getCurrentUser(data => {
    console.log('data: ', data); 
    this.username = data.name;
});
```